Why can't I read the Superblock in btrfs?
Why can't I read the Superblock in btrfs?
Was using my pc(arch) as usual with Android studio running , suddenly it got corrupted and asked to restart IDE as the file system became read only , I restarted entire pc and now I am unable to mount the btrfs system. Using Linux 6.6.60-1-lts, btrfs-progs v6.11
I chose btrfs as it's becoming the new default.
How do I fix this? So far I've tried:
liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs rescue super-recover /dev/sdb3
All supers are valid, no need to recover

liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs rescue zero-log /dev/sdb3
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
WARNING: could not setup csum tree, skipping it
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
ERROR: could not open ctree

liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs scrub start /dev/sdb3
ERROR: '/dev/sdb3' is not a mounted btrfs device

liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs scrub status /dev/sdb3
ERROR: '/dev/sdb3' is not a mounted btrfs device

liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo mount -o usebackuproot /dev/sdb3 /mnt
mount: /mnt: fsconfig system call failed: File exists.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs check /dev/sdb3
Opening filesystem to check...
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: root [7 0] level 0 does not match 2

ERROR: could not setup csum tree
ERROR: cannot open file system

Ran rescue as well:
liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs rescue chunk-recover /dev/sdb3
Scanning: DONE in dev0                        
corrupt leaf: root=1 block=713392128 slot=0, unexpected item end, have 16283 expect 0
leaf free space ret -3574, leaf data size 0, used 3574 nritems 11
leaf 713392128 items 11 free space -3574 generation 368940 owner ROOT_TREE
leaf 713392128 flags 0x1(WRITTEN) backref revision 1
fs uuid 6d8d36ba-d266-4b34-88ad-4f81c383a521
chunk uuid 52ed2048-4a76-4a75-bb75-e1a118ec8118
ERROR: leaf 713392128 slot 0 pointer invalid, offset 15844 size 439 leaf data limit 0
ERROR: skip remaining slots
corrupt leaf: root=1 block=713392128 slot=0, unexpected item end, have 16283 expect 0
leaf free space ret -3574, leaf data size 0, used 3574 nritems 11
leaf 713392128 items 11 free space -3574 generation 368940 owner ROOT_TREE
leaf 713392128 flags 0x1(WRITTEN) backref revision 1
fs uuid 6d8d36ba-d266-4b34-88ad-4f81c383a521
chunk uuid 52ed2048-4a76-4a75-bb75-e1a118ec8118
ERROR: leaf 713392128 slot 0 pointer invalid, offset 15844 size 439 leaf data limit 0
ERROR: skip remaining slots
Couldn't read tree root
open with broken chunk error

And restore after rescue:
liveuser@localhost-live:~$ sudo btrfs restore /dev/sdb3 /dev/sda5
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: root [7 0] level 0 does not match 2

WARNING: could not setup csum tree, skipping it
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: root [5 0] level 0 does not match 2

Could not open root, trying backup super
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: root [7 0] level 0 does not match 2

WARNING: could not setup csum tree, skipping it
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: root [5 0] level 0 does not match 2

Could not open root, trying backup super
ERROR: superblock bytenr 274877906944 is larger than device size 209715200000
Could not open root, trying backup super

The hard disk is healthy as per smartctl. No reallocated sectors, and other ntfs/ext4 partitions are working fine.
Atleast if its possible to recover the data. Thanks!
I'm devastated lost a data which was years efforts. Only backup I have of that is few months old so many changes I've done after that. :'(

Was able to recover data with following:
sudo btrfs-find-root /dev/sdb3  

output :
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711704576 wanted 368940 found 368652
WARNING: could not setup csum tree, skipping it
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
parent transid verify failed on 711655424 wanted 368940 found 368652
Superblock thinks the generation is 368940
Superblock thinks the level is 0
Found tree root at 713392128 gen 368940 level 0
Well block 711639040(gen: 368939 level: 0)

then
sudo btrfs restore -sxmSi -t 711639040 /dev/sdb3 /path/to/dest/

